# Set canvas height and width to the height and width of its containing div

Tags: html, css

I have the following code and would like to make the canvas the same size as my `div` with the class `canvas-wrap`:

```css
#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.canvas-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="canvas-wrap">
  <div class="row" id="overlay">
  </div>
  <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

Unfortunately at the moment it seems to default to 150x300. Would be better if it was the same size as the `div` with the class of `canvas-wrap`.

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong and fix the error?

Comment: Specifying width and height via CSS will only _scale_ the canvas, but not change its intrinsic pixel dimensions (“coordinate space”). You need to specify the `width` and `height` _attributes_ for the canvas (if you want a different coordinate space than the default 150x300px.)

Comment: Your code looks like it makes the overlay the same size as your canvas wrap (although moved down 20px).  You currently have no styles for your actual canvas

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set any style definitions on the canvas itself.

```css
#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
}

.canvas-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.canvas-wrap canvas {
  border: 1px solid magenta;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
}

body, .canvas-wrap {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="canvas-wrap">
  <div clas="row" id="overlay">
  </div>
  <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your help. Unfortunately, the canvas does not allow me to draw anything on it unless I explicitly set the height and width on the canvas tag, thus defeating the whole purpose. Any help with this?

Answer (score 0):

For my suggetion You have to mention the height and width of the div in css and also mention same width and height to the canvas. For example

```css
.canvas-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  height: 200px
}

.canvas-wrap canvas {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="canvas-wrap">
  <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

For my suggetion You have to mention the height and width of the div in css and also mention same width and height to the canvas. 
For example

.canvas-wrap {width:  100%;height: 100px;}